# Php lampp ubuntu

Tags: php, lampp, ubuntu

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему, установил убунту и веб сервер Lampp

Перенес сайты в /home/user/www, изменил в lampp пути к сайту, апач видит сайты, но php не может загрузится, пишет такую ошибку

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/user/www/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

Хелп.

Comment: удалить левый lamp, установить нормально. `apt-get install httpd php` (нужно конечно посмотреть, как там конкретно в убунте, может `apt-get install apache php5`). И на руткод.

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что он левый? : ) Он рабочий, просто нужно перенести сайты в домашнюю папку

Comment: исходя из этого `/opt/lampp/lib/php`.

> Он рабочий,

а в чем же тогда проблема:)

Comment: Он работал когда сайты хранились здесь /opt/lampp/htdocs/ но это не удобно, и я перенес сайты в /home/user/www и получаю ошибку которую писал выше, на убунту я пару дней : ) Если есть альтернативные веб серверы рад буду услышать

Comment: @dogmar Разберитесь с уровнями директорий.

Comment: ИМХО хранить файлы проекта в домашней папке - моветон

Если вам так удобнее с ними потом работать - сделайте симлинк:

    ln -s /opt/lampp/lib/php /home/user/www

Comment: Делал, сайты апач видит, а php прогрузится не может, а как по вашему правильнее?